# Export a web-page to a PDF with FPDF

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf, html-to-pdf

Complicated question with a (hopefully) simple answer.

I'm looking into FPDF to export a web-page to a PDF.  The web-page has been formatted for Print media, but since print media can be kind of iffy with CSS/HTML rendered object, I was hoping exporting to a PDF and then printing would make for less of a design headache.

I've scrounged through the FPDF website and I'm not seeing a function for the one thing I was hoping to see.  Some kind of `include()` function.  I see a bunch of lines about formatting content, which I'm hoping means

Am I over thinking this?  Can I simply use `include()` after the FPDF constructor and then any content from there in will be printed with the page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The FPDF library is not meant for directly rendering HTML markup into a PDF.

If that's what you're looking to do, you could try one of the solutions designed specifically for that purpose. For example, the [html2pdf library](http://html2pdf.fr/en/default), which among other things is based on the FPDF library. You can also consider using an external API like [DocRaptor](http://docraptor.com/), which is a cost-effective solution based on the very costly [Prince XML](http://www.princexml.com/) program.

Comment: html2pdf is the solution we ended up going with, for anyone researching this.  It prefers using tables for layout which is not ideal but manageable.