# trying to find php library or class to convert a .php or .html file into pdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I have already Used Fpdf and dompdf. dompdf seems better But it cannot generate more than three Image . Is there any Library except dompdf which can convert a html file into pdf ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export a web-page to a PDF with FPDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415370/export-a-web-page-to-a-pdf-with-fpdf/14415468#14415468)

Comment: Have a look at: [Website screenshots using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/757675/87015)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For a commercial product, I think hands down the best is [Prince XML](http://www.princexml.com)

For a free solution I've had a lot more luck with mPDF than with dompdf, probably because it's been around longer. Take a look at [MPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php)

There are a few others, but I think if you're already into this than those would be the best to explore and go from there.

Comment: Sure. The above comments are correct, there are a few answers that already cover this topic. I'd just add based on all that, personally I had the best experience with the two I mentioned.