# PDF cretaion of webpage with fpdf return blank

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I am trying to create direct pdf of webpage. so i am using fpdf for that.

I have kept fpdf files on fpdf folder and created a separate create-pdf.php file with following code :

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');
$url = $_GET[$url1];
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,$url);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

And used following php code to get current url of page of which pdf is to be created.

```
<?php
   $url1 = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
?>
```

And Created a Link to create pdf as follows :

```
<a href="fpdf/create-pdf.php" target="_blank">Create PDF</a>
```

Now pdf is getting created in new tab...but It is Empty / blank...No text is there on created pdf...

Comment: Have you tried testing with an absolute url?

Comment: @Daniel I just tried it with actual url....but it is printing only url in pdf....

Comment: what do you mean by printing on url in pdf?

Comment: @Daniel Url Used is seen in bold in pdf created...and no contect of that webapge....

Comment: Have you tried this solution --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415370/export-a-web-page-to-a-pdf-with-fpdf?rq=1